# How can I add multiple charts without repeating javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
function createChart(divId, data) {
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById(divId));

  option = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
      data: data,
      type: 'bar'
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
}

createChart('main1', [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]);
createChart('main2', [15,25,35,45,55,65,75]);
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main1" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<div id="main2" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It shows blank elemnts!
It shows this errors in Console:
ReferenceError: echarts is not defined
The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: What error are you facing? Can you please create a working instance ?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do that by creating a configurable function. For now, i have configured two properties div ID and data. You can make other properties configurable and passed to this common function.

Please find below the working code:

```js
function createChart(divId, data) {
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById(divId));

  option = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
      data: data,
      type: 'bar'
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
}

createChart('main', [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]);
createChart('main-2', [15,25,35,45,55,65,75]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>

<div id="main-2" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

This is the updated code, the javascript part should be at the bottom of the body tag. And i have changed uppercase tags to lowercase as per standard

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.7.0/echarts.min.js"></script>

<div id="main1" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
<div id="main2" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function createChart(divId, data) {
  var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById(divId));

  option = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
      data: data,
      type: 'bar'
    }]
  };

  myChart.setOption(option);
}

createChart('main1', [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]);
createChart('main2', [15,25,35,45,55,65,75]);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but can you explain for me why did you put the script inside body?

Comment: The problem was that echart library(script tag) was written after our code. But our code need echart libraray to work properly, thats why there is an error that echart is not defined. The other reason we need to add at javascript code at bottom of body tag is we want all the HTML code to load before execution of any JS code.